# jQuery Ajax function not working. Php code is working without errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to use AJAX to submit form data to a .TXT file using PHP code.
The results are getting added to the text file but AJAX functionality is not working. 
 Please let me know the error in my code.

Here is the Code for the form:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
<h1>AJAX Sign Up Form </h1>
<div id="form-messages"></div>
    <form id="signup" method="post" action="mailer.php">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Here is the jquery(2.1.1) code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sign_btn").click(function(event){
      var mail = $("#mail").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "mailer.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        data: mail
        })
        .done (function(data) { $('#form-messages').html(data) })
        .fail (function()  { $('#form-messages').append("Opps!An Error Occured.Try Again</p>")});


  });

});
```

Here is the mailer.php

```
<?php
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $fp = fopen("signup.txt", "a");
  $savestring = "$email\n";
  fwrite($fp, $savestring);
  fclose($fp);
  echo "<h1>Thank You For Subscribing</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: where is input field with `id="sign_btn"` ? How it will bind click event ?

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: @GBD omg! You are correct. That was a stupid mistake on my end. The issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

`data: mail`

use

`data: {email: mail}`

because, in PHP you're looking for `$_POST["email"]` which means, `$_POST` array has a key named `email` with some value.

Comment: I did that still not working. The success message is being shown on after the page is directed to mailer.php

Comment: add event.preventDefault(); to your js code before sending the ajax request

Comment: @smith09 Can you make a jsfiddle demo for us?

Comment: The issue is resolved now, I forgot to add the id to the button to bind the click

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }

})

    .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );

});
```

Send your data (as a object) above in my code 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You can go with any of the folowing :**

only if mail is an object that has all the input of a form like

`var mail = new FormData($(this)[0]);` // on form submit ofcourse

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "mailer.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        data: mail 
        })
        .done (function(data) { $('#form-messages').html(data) })
        .fail (function()  { $('#form-messages').append("Opps!An Error Occured.Try Again</p>")});
```

if you want to send a single variable via ajax to php then give the data its key so that you can access it by that key in php like this

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "mailer.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            data: "mail=" + mail,
            })
            .done (function(data) { $('#form-messages').html(data) })
            .fail (function()  { $('#form-messages').append("Opps!An Error Occured.Try Again</p>")});
```

Comment: Thank you issue is resolved, added the id="sign_btn" to button to bind the click

Answer (score 0):

The button id is missing in the form code...